# запустить стороннюю программу из под node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Хочу включить **excel** из под **node.js**
о я не понимаю что **node.js** от меня хочет, если команду вставить в терминал - работает

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
spawn('"C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 5/program/scalc.exe"');
```

[image: код ошибки]

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для кусков кода не на JS/HTML/CSS следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: а какой результат вы получаете?

Comment: И это явно не Excel.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Я добавил на что ругается, но мне эта ошибка ничего не говорит...

Comment: @D-side Да, не ексель... у меня просто нет экселя) поэтому Calc

Comment: ENOENT = Error NO ENTry = Нет такого файла или папки. И у вас как минимум слэши в пути не в ту сторону. Хотя сомневаюсь, что проблема в этом.

Comment: @D-side вроде винда на счет слешей полиглот - допускает в обе стороны.

Comment: Лишние кавычки уберите

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод exec:

```
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var runLibreOffice =function(){
   exec('C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 5/program/scalc.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}
runLibreOffice();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!))) все работает!!))

Comment: Теперь у меня другая проблема, как открыть файл: 'C:/Program Files/LibreOffice 5/program/scalc.exe C:/some file.ods'